# Something is wrong with attaching navigationProperties when done in different orders

Tags: breeze

So I have three entity types:

```
addType
name: 'DaySchedule'
apiVersion: 3
dataProperties:
  uid: "uid"
  employee_id: "int"
  day: "string"
  shifts:
    complexType: "Shift"
    hasMany: true
navigationProperties:
  employee:
    type: "Employee"
    assoc: "DayScheduleEmployee"
    key: ["employee_id"]

addType
name: 'Employee'
dataProperties:
  id: "id"
  details:
    complexType: "EmployeeDetails"
navigationProperties:
  schedules:
    entityTypeName: "DaySchedule"
    hasMany: true
    associationName: "DayScheduleEmployee"
  attendanceDays:
    entityTypeName: "AttendanceDay"
    hasMany: true
    associationName: "AttendanceDayEmployee"

apiSchemaHelper.addType
name: "AttendanceDay"
apiVersion: 3
dataProperties:
  uid: "uid"
  employee_id: "int"
  date: "string"
  shifts:
    complexType: "AttendanceShift"
    hasMany: true
navigationProperties:
  employee:
    type: "Employee"
    assoc: "AttendanceDayEmployee"
    key: ["employee_id"]
```

So as you see, employee has many DaySchedule and AttendanceDay objects.

If I create three objects of this type in the following order:

```
employee = createEntity "Employee", id: 20
daySchedule = createEntity "DaySchedule", employee_id: 20
attendanceDay = createEntity "AttendanceDay", employee_id: 20
```

Then all the navigationProperties are correctly made.
However if I put employee creation last:

```
daySchedule = createEntity "DaySchedule", employee_id: 20
attendanceDay = createEntity "AttendanceDay", employee_id: 20
employee = createEntity "Employee", id: 20
```

Then employee.schedules is as expected, but employee.attendanceDays is an empty array.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue. This could be a possible bug. In any case, I'm letting the Breeze lead architect know about it and I will post as soon as I have an update. Thanks for reporting this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a bug and is now fixed in the breeze.js GitHub repo.  This fix will also be included in the next full breeze.js release (1.4.14) out sometime next week.